# How I can link a file with another in React.js

Tags: reactjs, import, hyperlink

I am trying to link a **file**, but I don't know how how to import it. I am attempting to redirect to login into a form. My code:

```
import home from './home.js';
```

and the form is: `<form action="./home.js">`
Maybe there is another way for it to work?

Thanks if you help!

Comment: You can't do that. You'll need something handling your routing, whether it's client side routing with React or server side routing which renders another component at a different url.

Comment: Do you mean to use React-router dom?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good option

Comment: I just imported it and now it doesn't show any errors. Thanks.